# How come my external JS file won't load in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, external

I can't for the life of me figure out why this external JS file isn't loading. I've tried every help question out there and it still won't work so maybe someone else can see what I can't.

So I'm working on a ReactJS project and I'm trying to link an external JS file.

Here is the file structure:
[image]

The external javascript file is in `public/js/script.js`.

I've tried every method I've found to get it to work.

I've linked it in `index.html` as follows:

```
<script src="./js/script.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

I've added the following to my main App component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        let url = '../public/js/script.js'
        script.src = url;   //(This is external js url)
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }
```

I've added this into the functional component where I really need the external javascript to work:

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '../public/js/script.js';   //(This is external js url)
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }, [])
```

And yet not matter any of these attempts nothing seems to make the file work.

I am running the project on localhost, so I'm not sure if there's an issue there. I'd just like to figure out how to make external javascript files work. I've tried using Helmet.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyways, appreciate any help I can get trying to figure this out.

Edit:
I did adjust the following:
`src="./js/script.js`
to
`src="js/script.js` in the `<script>` tag
and it also has had no effect. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me

1. I used **useEffect hook inside a function component** (before return). This can be used inside App.js also before return. Note: if you want to do this inside a class which extends `React.component` then you need to use `componentDidMount()` (before render), this is required as hooks work inside a  function component or custom hooks only.
2. In the **header add a script tag**

3. **Small Snippet of the code :**

   ```
   import React, from "react";

   React.useEffect(() => {


     const LoadExternalScript = () => {
         const externalScript = document.createElement("script");
         externalScript.onerror = loadError;
         externalScript.id = "external";
         externalScript.async = true;
         externalScript.type = "text/javascript";
         externalScript.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
         document.body.appendChild(externalScript);
         externalScript.src = './script.js';
   };
   LoadExternalScript();


     return () => {

       // document.body.removeChild(externalScript);
     };
   }, []);
   ```
4. You will find this link useful if you get a syntax error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in React" [Syntax error solution](https://hashnode.com/post/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-less-in-react-cjsh3ocr301m84ws2xkfxmcdv)

Answer (score 2):

Original Code:

```
<script src="./js/script.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

Changed code: (changed to relative directory)

```
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

Comment: I was going to say I feel like an idiot but I changed that as well and it's not working. Not sure why any of these other solutions I've tried don't seem to load the js file either. Almost every question I've come across related to this problem suggest using componentDidMount and useEffect and even those aren't working for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Put `/js/script.js` inside public folder, then add this line beetwen `head` tag. (no dot prefix)

If you put under `body` tag, this line will be overwritten when React start to render elements.

```
<script src="/js/script.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

Or, another way; try to change this line:

> let url = '../public/js/script.js'

to:

> let url = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/js/script.js`